# Fetch value from dynamically generated Panel Controls

Tags: c#

I m adding panel controls in a flowlayoutpanel dynamically as per the number of records in my table. i want to get id from each of the panels so that i can open a popup window on click event of panel. Any sugestions?

here is my code sample.

```
        int id=0;
        public void FillSearch()
        {
            var playerList = dianaDB.TblPlayers.Where(p => p.Status == "Active" & p.CancellationStatus == "Active" & p.Version == "Active").Select(p => p);
            Panel pnlPlayer = new Panel();
            foreach (var pl in playerList)
            {
                pnlPlayer = new Panel();
                pnlPlayer.Size = new Size(153, 116);
                pnlPlayer.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                pnlPlayer.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                pnlPlayer.Click += new EventHandler(pbx_Click);
                id=pl.Id;
            }
        }


        private void pbx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            DlgSearchDetails newDlg = new DlgSearchDetails(id);
            newDlg.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the `ID` of a panel in its [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property.

```
pnlPlayer.Tag = id;
```

Then retrieve it later

```
private void pbx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

    Panel p = sender as Panel;
    if(p != null)
    { 
       //TODO add error handling to ensure Tag contains an int
       //...
       DlgSearchDetails newDlg = new DlgSearchDetails((int)p.Tag);
       newDlg.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming , you are asking about the WinForm
There is a [tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property in each controls , ypou can utilize it.

```
 public void FillSearch()
    {
        var playerList = dianaDB.TblPlayers.Where(p => p.Status == "Active" & p.CancellationStatus == "Active" & p.Version == "Active").Select(p => p);
        Panel pnlPlayer = new Panel();
        foreach (var pl in playerList)
        {
            pnlPlayer = new Panel();
            pnlPlayer.Size = new Size(153, 116);
            pnlPlayer.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            pnlPlayer.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            pnlPlayer.Click += new EventHandler(pbx_Click);
            pnlPlayer.Tag = pl.Id;
        }
    }


    private void pbx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
         var panle = sender as Panel;
         if(panel!=null)
         {
           DlgSearchDetails newDlg = new DlgSearchDetails(panel.Tag);
           newDlg.ShowDialog();
         }

    }
```